# Multiline Messages in Message Bundles

Tags: grails, internationalization

I would like to make use of the message bundles feature in grails, but always run into the problem that I need multiline messages for text (instructions or help text for example).

Is there a way to create multiline messages or do I have to create single line messages with `<br />`s or `\n`s in between?

Or is it the wrong approach for longer text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can simply end the line with a trailing slash (\) and continue on the next line in Java Properties files.

See: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0503.html